# How to delete all the files/folders from the folder except few folders?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, rm, delete-directory

I am trying to write maintainer scripts for `debian` package.
Assume that I have a directory structure as follows:

```
application/
----application/file1.txt
----application/file2.txt
----application/config
--------application/config/c1.conf
--------application/config/c2.conf
----application/logs
--------application/logs/l1.txt
--------application/logs/l2.txt
----application/src
--------application/src/static/
------------application/src/static/js
------------application/src/static/css
--------application/src/s1.py
--------application/src/s2.py
----application/lib
--------application/src/js/
--------application/src/css/
```

Now I want to delete all the files/folders except `config` and `logs` (in this case, `src` and `lib` folders, and `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` files). My `PWD` is currently a parent of `appliaction/` dir (i.e., I can see `application` in my `PWD`).

What command should I use (a small `bash script` would be great)? (I tried with `rm -rf` with some options but mistakenly deleted other files, so I would like to know the correct answer before trying anything else!)

Comment: What options did you try? Because you can do this with plain `rm` (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather, there's a bunch of other folders other than `src` because otherwise you would just use `rm -rf src`.

If your `PWD` is `application`, i.e. you're in the parent directory of `config` `logs` and `src`, you just need a way to use `rm -rf` on all files/folders except `config` and `log`, so why not make a for loop?

```
    #!/bin/bash

    cd "/path/to/application"

    for file in * ; do
            case "$file" in
                    config )
                            echo "file is $file: doing nothing"
                    ;;
                    logs )
                            echo "file is $file: doing nothing"
                    ;;
                    * )
                            echo "file is $file: removing"
                            rm -rf "$file"
                    ;;
                    esac
            done
    exit 0
```

Comment: This does not delete the files.

Comment: Please check the original post under the edits. It said folders specifically. "files/folders" was added into the question after I had provided my answer. In any case, to remove the files as well, just remove the if statement from the above and provided there aren't any files named config or logs withouth any extension this script will work as intended.

Comment: Ah, I hate it when people change their question that significantly. But maybe good then to remove the if-statement to keep it consistent?

Comment: Sure, change made. I'm new to these forums and not so sure what the etiquette is when the original post is changed well after a correct answer is provided. If you hadn't  pointed out the updated question I probably would never have checked this.

Comment: Well, it is not really appreciated normally, but in this case it doesn't hurt to much. I upvoted because this solution should work, altough I think mine is better ;)

Answer (score 1):

This must work:

```
find ./application -depth -mindepth 1 -type d \
  -regextype posix-extended ! -regex ".*\/(config|logs).*" | \
  -exec rm -fr {}  \;
```

Or with `xargs` if you don't have folder names with newlines in them you can write:

```
find ./application -depth -mindepth 1 -type d \
  -regextype posix-extended ! -regex ".*\/(config|logs).*" | \
  xargs -t -I {} rm -fr {}
```

Or with `xargs` if you have folder names with newlines in them you can use:

```
find ./application -depth -mindepth 1 -type d \
  -regextype posix-extended ! -regex ".*\/(config|logs).*" -print0 | \
  xargs -0 -t -I {} rm -fr {}
```

- `find` finds all directories below `./application` excluding those that have `/config` and `/logs` and prints them starting with the lowest
- `xargs` runs removing the directory

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just deleting the `application/application/src` dir, there is no reason to use find, etc.. All you need to do is:

```
rm -rf application/application/src
```

**remaining:**

```
application/application/logs/l2.txt
application/application/logs/l1.txt
application/application/config/c1.conf
application/application/config/c2.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd application
find . -type d | egrep -v '(^\./$|^\./log|^\./config)' | while read DIR
do
   echo rm -rf $DIR
done
```

This uses find to list all the directories, pipes through grep to exclude the ones we want to keep (also to exclude "./" which would be the PWD), and pipes that filtered list to the while loop which does the delete. I've put the "echo" in there so you can test if this does what you actually want. If you're happy then remove the echo. SInce the the returned list (DIR) would be in tree order, e.g. d1, d1/d1a, d1/d1b, and rm -rf d1 would remove the lower folders, you might want to add a "if [ -d $DIR ]" around the rm -rf.

Comment: Oops, too late, my answer is along the sames as skwilsp's. He got in whilsts I was writing mine. I think his is more concise though.

Comment: Never use capitalized variables in bash, keep those reversed for system variables.

Answer (score 0):

Using Bash:

```
for file in applications/*; do
    target="${file#*/}"
    if [[ $target != config && $target != logs ]]; then
        rm -rf "$file"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for complicated `find` commands, just use the shell (assuming you are in the application folder):

```
rm -r !(logs|config)
```

This is referred to as "Pathname Expansion", from `man bash`

> ```
>          !(pattern-list)
>                 Matches anything except one of the given patterns
> ```